# Why can't we use linear regression for discrete Y?

Tags: regression, self-study, ordinal-data, regression-strategies

This text is from An Introduction to Statistical Learning with Applications in R(by • Gareth James • Daniela Witten • Trevor Hastie • Robert Tibshirani)
List item
Can anyone help me by making linear models with these different variable so that I can practically understand what is wrong with these

> Suppose that we are trying to predict the medical condition of a
>   patient in the emergency room on the basis of her symptoms. In this
>   simpliﬁed example, there are three possible diagnoses: stroke, drug
>   overdose, and epileptic seizure. We could consider encoding these
>   values as a quantitative response variable, Y , as follows:
>
> y=1 if stroke;
>
> y= 2 if drug overdose;
>
> y= 3 if  epileptic seizure.
>
> Using this coding, least squares could be used to ﬁt a linear
>   regression model to predict Y on the basis of a set of predictors
>   X1,...,Xp. Unfortunately, this coding implies an ordering on the
>   outcomes, putting drug overdose in between stroke and epileptic
>   seizure, and insisting that the diﬀerence between stroke and drug
>   overdose is the same as the diﬀerence between drug overdose and
>   epileptic seizure. In practice there is no particular reason that this
>   needs to be the case.
>
> For instance, one could choose an equally reasonable coding,
>
> y=1 if epileptic seizure;
>
> y=2 if stroke;
>
> y=3 if drug overdose.
>
> which would imply a totally diﬀerent relationship among the three
>   conditions. Each of these coding would produce fundamentally diﬀerent
>   linear models that would ultimately lead to diﬀerent sets of
>   predictions on test observations.

please help me to understand this that

1)how to produce linear model using any of the relationship

2)how different relationship among the three condition produce different linear model

Comment: What is unclear for you in this example?

Comment: Hint: what would it mean if your model returned prediction of 2.5 or 4..?

Comment: @Tim I didn't understand how these coding produce different linear model and how to produce linear model using these

Comment: @NickCox Now i update . Thanks to your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

There are two viable models for this situation and neither of them is close to the linear model (ordinary least squares).

1. Multinomial logistic model, which doesn't assume an ordering of $Y$ but which requires twice as many $\beta$ coefficients with a 3-level $Y$.
2. Ordinal regression (e.g., proportional odds ordinal logistic model) which makes a strong ordering assumption about $Y$ (but no spacing assumptions) and only needs as many $\beta$s as the linear model, plus 2 intercepts for 3-level $Y$.

To me it is not useful to conceptualize this using a model for continuous $Y$.

I changed the original title of the question, which included the word *classification*.  Classification has nothing to do with the issues at hand.

Comment: They mentioned in the text that it is possible to build linear model using binary variable and i am curious to find out how .Just wanted to know from you is it possible to build linear model using binary variable 0 and 1 ? Please clear the confusion as you are an expert in this field

Comment: Why would anyone be interested in a linear model for binary $Y$ when it would yield "probabilities" <0 or >1?  To answer your question it is possible.  Lots of things are possible that are terrible ideas.

Comment: Well I am bit curious to learn by going to the bottom of the subject. Helpful if you provide any link or way to create linear model using binary variable.

Comment: What you want in terms of a "linear model using binary variable" is explained farther down the page in the text that you cite (page 130): the section on logistic regression. You use a transformation of the probabilities, the logit, as the outcome variable rather than raw probabilities. That avoids the inconsistencies that Frank Harrell points out in his comment. Some ways to handle multiple discrete outcomes are covered later in the same Chapter 4 of ISLR. Try the exercises at the end of the chapter.

Comment: @FrankHarrell "Classification has nothing to do with the issues at hand." I would love to hear your explanation about why this isn't a classification problem.

Comment: See http://fharrell.com/post/classification .  Even though Y is categorical that doesn't imply that you want to classify new observations into one of the Y categories.  Close calls makes it far better to estimate all the class membership probabilities given X.  This is not the act of classification.